# How mysql add count colnum to a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tableA and want add count colnum to it , count is total rows of tableA and is same at all rows in result table ,tableA like below :

- note: table A is result of other query

tableA

```
id | name  | rank |
-------------------
1  | John  |  12  |
2  | Maria |  18  |
3  | Steph |  44  |
4  | Jay   |  17  |
```

and result should be :

```
id | name  | rank | total | rank/total 
---------------------------------------
1  | John  |  12  |  4    |    3
2  | Maria |  18  |  4    |    4.5
3  | Steph |  44  |  4    |    11
4  | Jay   |  17  |  4    |    4.25
```

how can do that with MYSQL

Comment: This has been answered several times on SO already.  Did you search prior to asking?

Comment: @Ageonix yes but not find any answer , can help me to find ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the total rows in your table, do this:

```
SELEcT count(*) FROM TableA
```

You can then combine this query in the `SELEcT` of another query and make a computation from it, which gives this :

```
SELEcT *, (SELEcT count(*) FROM TableA) AS total, rank / (SELEcT count(*) FROM TableA) AS 'rank/total'  
FROM  tableA
```

if tableA is the result of another query, do

```
SELEcT *, (SELEcT count(*) FROM TableA) AS total, rank / (SELEcT count(*) FROM TableA) AS 'rank/total'  
FROM  ( insert_the_other_query_here ) tableA
```

Comment: from note how i can refer to table A when it's not real table ?

Comment: instead of doing `FROM tableA`, do `FROM ( insert_your_query_here )  tableA`

Comment: problem is tableA generated from heavy query that took 1 sec , if i repeat it 3 time's in answer , it's call that query 3 times to show result

Comment: the main problem here is that you ask a question and not give a third of the hints and context needed to provide you with a correct answer...

Comment: mysql return : `Table 'mydb.tablea' doesn't exist `

Comment: is any way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if using a variable helps you helps you:

`SET @total = SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tableA;`

`SELECT name, rank, @total AS total, rank/@total AS 'rank/total' FROM tableA;`

Comment: note: table A is result of other query , and is heavy query that took 1-2 sec

Comment: well compared to the other suggestions it executes the query only twice. Not sure where to further improve performance. You could read your tableA query into a separate table or create a view from it but I doubt it speeds up the thing significantly.

Comment: maybe you want to share your "tableA" query with us, maybe there's the actual place to look for improvements